# Why does the input not work?

Tags: javascript

Some folks have been very generous and helped me put together the following code.  It's not throwing any errors in Chrome Console, but the input doesn't work.  None of the commands you type will perform their function.  I've stared at this til I'm blue, but don't see where I created the error.  Any ideas?

```js
 var rooms = {
     northWest: {
         name: "North West",
         hasSword: true,
         paths: {
             east: "northEast",
             south: "southWest"
         }
     },
     northEast: {
         name: "North East",
         paths: {
             west: "northWest",
             south: "southEast"
         }
     },
     southWest: {
         name: "South West",
         paths: {
             east: "southEast",
             north: "northWest"
         }
     },
     southEast: {
         name: "South East",
         paths: {
             west: "southWest",
             north: "northEast"
         }
     },
 };

 // Set Current Room

 var currentRoom = rooms["northWest"];

 $(document).ready(function() {

     $("form").submit(function() {
         var input = $("#commandLine").val();

         // this is a plugin to insert the repetitive lines throughout the code

         $.fn.properDisplay = function() {
             return this.hide().insertBefore("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000);
         };

         // this is a function to use the "I don't understand" statement   throughout the code

         function understand() {
             $("<p>I don't understand " + input + ".</p>").properDisplay();
         };



         //This is a function to travel from one room to the next

         var travel = function(direction) {
             var newRoom = rooms[currentRoom.paths[direction]];
             if (!newRoom) {
                 $("<p>You can't go that way.</p>").properDisplay();
             } else {
                 currentRoom = newRoom;
                 $("<p>You are now in the " + currentRoom.name + " Room.          </p>").properDisplay();
             }
         };

         // This is the take sword function

         var takeSword = function() {
             if (currentRoom.hasSword) {
                 $("<p>You picked up a sword.</p>").properDisplay();
             } else {
                 $("<p>The sword is not here.</p>").properDisplay();
             }
         };


         var receiveInput = function(input) {
             switch (input) {
                 case "help":
                     $("#messageHelp").properDisplay();
                     break;
                 case "take sword":
                     takeSword();
                     break;
                 case "go east":
                     travel("east");
                     break;
                 case "go west":
                     travel("west");
                     break;
                 case "go north":
                     travel("north");
                     break;
                 case "go south":
                     travel("south");
                     break;
             }
         }


         $("#commandLine").val("");
     });
 });
```

Comment: At first glance: your `receiveInput()` function is never called. To fix: at the end of your `$.("#form")...` function, add `receiveInput(input);`

Comment: Thank you @wintvelt.  It took me a day to figure out where to add that.  I was putting it higher up in the `$("form").submit(function() {` section.  Just figured out where to put it.  Thanks again for the help.  Everything works perfectly now.

Comment: Posted it as answer too.. Glad to hear it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance: your `receiveInput()` function is never called.

To fix: at the end of your `$.("#form")...` function, add

```
receiveInput(input);
```

Comment: To clarify, it works when I put it under

` $("#commandLine").val("");`